# Managing execution time for PHP script, that is executing at every one minute from cpanel server

Tags: php, cron, execution

There is php script, which is executing on one minute of interval from server cron
job.

It is working fine with little data.But it may create problem, when data grows and execution time for the script is exceed more than one minute.Is there any solution to get rid of it?

Any suggestion for this will be great helpful for me.

Comment: Speed up the code or make the data smaller.

Comment: What do you mean by "get rid of it"? To get rid of it, just add a `#` to the beginning of the relevant line in the crontab file.

Comment: I mean how can I handle,  if the execution time exceed than one minute